# Entered GES/GOES Application ID or Date of Birth is incorrect or not available with Passport Seva System

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, vfs-global, global-entry

I completed my application on 01/09, but still shows the same message. Any idea how long it will take?
Also the Passport place of Issue - I'm typing in as India instead of the actual place of Issue (which is a city in India) because I gave India in GOES application, is that correct?

Comment: Your passport will have a Place of Issue printed on the details page, you enter that as the Place of Issue.

Comment: By 01/09 do you mean September 1 or January 9?

Comment: Applied on January 9th 2023